# ¿Como accedo a una vista si es usuario normal y a otra vista si es administrador usando un mismo controlador?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Quería acceder a una vista por medio de una función en un controlador si era administrador y a otra vista mediante esa misma función del mismo controlador  para el usuario, pero no se si esto es posible o si me va a dar problemas a la larga, por ahora yo había hecho lo siguiente:

```
public function store(LibroFormRequest $request)
{
    $libro= new Libro();
    $libro->lib_no=0;
    $libro->lib_titulo=$request->get('lib_titulo');
    $libro->lib_direccion_web=$request->get('lib_direccion_web');

    $autorid=$request->get('lib_autor_id');
    $autor=new Autor();

    if($autorid=="" || $autorid==0){
        $autor->atr_no=0;
        $usuario_actual=\Auth::user();
        $autor->atr_nombre_artistico=$usuario_actual->nombre;
        $autor->atr_cliente_id=$usuario_actual->id_usuario;
        $autor->atr_activo=1;
        $autor->save();

        $autorid=DB::table('autor')->orderBy('id_autor', 'desc')
            ->first();
        $autor2=Autor::findOrFail($autorid->id_autor);
        $autor2->atr_no=$autorid->id_autor+1;
        $autor2->update();
    }

    $fecha=$request->get('lib_fecha_creacion');

    if($fecha==""|| $fecha==null){
        $fecha=Carbon::now('Europe/Madrid');
    }

    $libro->lib_fecha_creacion=$fecha->toDateString();
    $libro->lib_precio=$request->get('lib_precio');
    $libro->lib_genero_literario_id=$request->get('lib_genero_literario');

    if($autorid=="" || $autorid==0){
        $libro->lib_autor_id=$autor->id_autor;
    }else{
        $libro->lib_autor_id=$autorid;
    }
    $libro->lib_activo=1;
    $libro->save();

    $libroid=DB::table('libro')->orderBy('id_libro', 'desc')
        ->first();
    $libro2=Libro::findOrFail($libroid->id_libro);
    $libro2->atr_no=$libroid->id_libro+1;
    $libro2->update();

    return Redirect::to('almacen/libro');
}
```

No se como debería añadir la nueva redirección puesto que estoy usando una ruta de tipo resource:

```
Route::resource('almacen/libro', 'LibroController');
```

Me gustaría que me echaran un cable por aquí con la decisión porque no se que es lo correcto en este caso, por ello les pregunto. Gracias por leerme hasta aquí. 

Un saludo.

Comment: Por lo que entendí: ¿quieres algo así como una vista independiente para el administrador y otra para el usuario?

Comment: Exáctamente PAGANA. Solo que quiero usar el mismo controlador para no tener que duplicar código, porque creo que esto debería ser posible, claro que al ser novata en esto de Laravel pues no se si se puede o simplemente me tengo que aguantar y generar código también para la otra vista. Supongo que es una duda de novata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Claro que es posible.

Suponiendo que tengas en tu tabla Users estos tres campos
(obviamente no iguales):

```
+-----------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
|id_usuario |alias_usuario |tipo_usuario |contra_usuario |
|___________|______________|_____________|_______________|
|1          |dolar         |admin        |mucha_plata    |
|___________|______________|_____________|_______________|
|2          |peluso        |usuario      |pulgoso        |
|           |              |             |               |
+----------------------------------------+---------------+
```

Una vez que tu usuario se haya logueado vas a poder acceder
a sus propiedades a través de este método:

```
Auth::user();
```

**Funcionamiento**

Si quisieras saber cuál es el id del usuario logueado
tendrías que hacerlo así:

```
Auth::user()->id_usuario
```

Si quisieras saber cuál es la contra del usuario podrías
hacerlo de esta manera:

```
Auth::user()->contra_usuario
```

**Resolviendo tu problema...**

Si quisieras saber cuando el usuario es admin o usuario
limitado podrías obtenerlo de esta manera:

```
Auth::user()->tipo_usuario
```

Para mostrar la vista indicada después de conocer si es
usuario limitado o admin puedes implementar un if/else
en tu controlador:

```
if((Auth::check()) && (Auth::user()->tipo_usuario)=="admin"){
    //Es admin =)
    return redirect()->route('mi.vista.de.admin');
}elseif((Auth::check()) && (Auth::user()->tipo_usuario)=="usuario"){
    //Es usuario =|
    return redirect()->route('mi.vista.de.usuario');
}else{
    //No invitado =(
    return redirect()->route('mi.vista.de.logueo')
                     ->withErrors('Inicie sesión primero');
}
```

Comment: Lo he entendido, ¡ahora falta implementarlo! Pero no parece dificil, ¡muchas gracias por la explicación!